# LESS lazy load issue - styles for ltr and rtl languages in same css file using mixins and variables

Tags: css, less, lazy-loading

I have been provided with less files containing mixins and styles for LTR as well as RTL content on a webpage. The webpage shows only one type of content at a time, either LTR or RTL. Although I could have separate css for LTR and RTL styles and control which file is being loaded, I want them both to be in the same css file.

The mixins are controlled with an @lang variable as follows:

```
// file: mixins.less
.myMixin() when (@lang = ltr){
    float: left;
}

.myMixin() when (@lang = rtl){
    float: right;
}
```

The mixins are being used in a styles.less file:

```
// file : styles.less
.myDiv{
    .myMixin();
}
```

I want to output both the ltr and rtl styles in the same css by importing the styles.less file twice but with different value of the @lang variable for each import :

```
@import "mixin.less";

@lang: ltr;
@import (multiple) "styles.less";

@lang: rtl;
html{
    [dir=rtl] & {
        @import (multiple) "styles.less";
    }   
}
```

But this is obviously not working due to LESS's lazy loading of variables.

Expected output in the css file:

```
.myDiv {
  float:left;
}
[dir=rtl] html .myDiv {
  float:right;
}
```

Actual output in the css file:

```
.myDiv {
  float:right;
}
[dir=rtl] html .myDiv {
  float:right;
}
```

**I do not have the liberty to modify the mixins.less file or the styles.less file.** How would I go about achieving both ltr and rtl styles in the same css file?

Thanks in advance.

---

Link for @seven-phases-max : [Example](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%2F%2FMXINS%5Cn.myMixin()%20when%20(%40lang%20%3D%20ltr)%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20float%3A%20left%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.myMixin()%20when%20(%40lang%20%3D%20rtl)%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20float%3A%20right%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%40lang%3A%20ltr%3B%5Cn%2F%2F%20%40import%20%5C%22styles%5C%22%3B%5Cnhtml%20%7B%5Cn%20%20.myMixin()%3B%20%2F%2Ffloat%20should%20be%20left%5Cn%20%20result%3A%20%40lang%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%26%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20%3C-%20unnamed%20namespace%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40lang%3A%20rtl%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20html%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20.myMixin()%3B%20%20%2F%2Ffloat%20should%20be%20right%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20result%3A%20%40lang%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%22%7D)

Comment: Isolate the scope of either variable. [Example](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%40lang%3A%20ltr%3B%5Cn%2F%2F%20%40import%20%5C%22styles%5C%22%3B%5Cnhtml%20%7Bresult%3A%20%40lang%3B%7D%5Cn%5Cn%26%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20%3C-%20unnamed%20namespace%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40lang%3A%20rtl%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20html%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20result%3A%20%40lang%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%40import%20(multiple)%20%5C%22styles%5C%22%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%22%7D). For your example above the simplest way is to move `@lang: rtl;` right into `html {}` block.

Comment: @seven-phases-max Unnamed namespaces work fine as long as we are directly using the variable. But don't work with mixins. Please check this : (link too long hence added to the bottom of the question)

Comment: Put the mixin into the same scope (for example by importing it together with "style.less").

Comment: @seven-phases-max Brilliant! It works. How do I credit you for this? Can you add your comments as an answer? It might help others looking for something similar.

Comment: Yes, please add an answer (honestly I'm too lazy to do it myself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the answer myself based on seven-phases-max's [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47651879/less-lazy-load-issue-styles-for-ltr-and-rtl-languages-in-same-css-file-using-m?noredirect=1#comment82263261_47651879).

Previously the scope of the `@lang` variable was the same throughout and when lazy-loading kicked in, `@lang` was allocated the most recent value given to it. We need to isolate the scope when changing the value of `@lang` by adding an unnamed namespace and then importing the mixins and styles in the same scope which will produce the desired result.

Below is the code snippet:

```
@lang: ltr;
@import "mixin.less"; // value of @lang is ltr
@import "styles.less"; // creates ltr styles

& {
    @lang: rtl;
    html{
        [dir=rtl] & {
            @import (multiple) "mixin.less"; // value of @lang is rtl
            @import (multiple) "styles.less"; // creates rtl styles
        }   
    }
}
```

Output is as expected:

```
.myDiv {
  float: left;
}
[dir=rtl] html .myDiv {
  float: right;
}
```